# Default MenuItem TopLevelHeader Control Template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Where can I get the MenuItem TopLevelHeader Control Template? The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296.aspx) link for styling menu items gives a modified template.

[image]

I need to obtain a control template that contains a default pop-up/context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manny tools are available that will serve the purpose like [stylesnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) and [Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/2091)

but if you have [Microsoft Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend%5FOverview.aspx) you can extract the default control template by

1. Draggint the control onto the design
   surface
2. Right click the control and choose
   Edit Template -> Edit Copy

When you do this, Blend will extract the base template from the control and explicitly declare it within document/application as a resource which you can then edit to your liking.

Check this for more

http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2009/01/wpf-kid-stuff-extracting-a-control-template.html

Answer (score 1):

I could not get Blend or the usual tools to access that control template but you can extract it yourself with code like the following:

```
var controlTemplate = (ControlTemplate)FindResource(MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey);
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var xml = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = true });
XamlWriter.Save(controlTemplate, xml);
var xaml = sb.ToString();
Debug.WriteLine(xaml);
```

The output is too long to include here.